# Multiple inputs to Keras Sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sequential

I am trying to merge output from two models and give them as input to the third model using keras sequential model. 
Model1 :

```
inputs1 = Input(shape=(750,))
x = Dense(500, activation='relu')(inputs1)
x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
```

Model1 :

```
inputs2 = Input(shape=(750,))
y = Dense(500, activation='relu')(inputs2)
y = Dense(100, activation='relu')(y)
```

Model3 :

```
merged = Concatenate([x, y])
final_model = Sequential()
final_model.add(merged)
final_model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
final_model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

Till here, my understanding is that, output from two models as x and y are merged and given as input to the third model. But when I fit this all like,

```
module3.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
module3.fit([in1, in2], np_res_array)
```

in1 and in2 are two numpy ndarray of dimention 10000*750 which contains my training data and np_res_array is the corresponding target.
 **This gives me error as 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'** As far as know, this is how we give multiple inputs to a model, but what is this error? How do I resolve it?

Comment: for future readers (and me too).  I assume in1 and inputs1 are the same as well as module3 and final_model.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do this using Sequential API. That's because of two reasons:

1. Sequential models, as their name suggests, are a sequence of layers where each layer is connected directly to its previous layer and therefore they cannot have branches (e.g. merge layers, multiple input/output layers, skip connections, etc.).
2. The `add()` method of Sequential API accepts a `Layer` instance as its argument and not a `Tensor` instance.  In your example `merged` is a Tensor (i.e. concatenation layer's output).

Further, the correct way of using `Concatenate` layer is like this:

```
merged = Concatenate()([x, y])
```

However, you can also use `concatenate` (note the lowercase "c"), its equivalent functional interface, like this:

```
merged = concatenate([x, y])
```

Finally, to be able to construct that third model you also need to use the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Comment: Thank You. I was mixing Sequential and Functional, so it was not working and also my Concatenate was wrong. :)