# How to train a dual streams inputs of CNN model with two DataIterator(s)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, training-data

I'm building a convolutional neural network (CNN) model consisting of dual stream image data input of `'RGB'` channels and `'grayscale'` channel converging into singular stream of shape `(None, width, height, 4*C)`, then `Dense()`.

[image: dummy example of the streaming infrastructure]

With big dataset, I must / forced to utilise `<class 'ImageDataGenerator'>`:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
```

and flow the dataset via directory:

```
train_C = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    ... , 
    color_mode = 'rgb', 
    ...
)

train_gr = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    ... , 
    color_mode = 'grayscale', 
    ... 
)
```

Unfortunately, to train the model with `fit` method as the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55234203/11000933):

```
model.fit( x = [input_1, input_2], ... )
```

it raised the following error:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'keras_preprocessing.image.directory_iterator.DirectoryIterator'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

So, how should I resolve this issue?

Note: *Python 3.X & Tensorflow 2.X*

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare your combined train generator : `train_generator = zip(train_C, train_gr)`
2. Concatenate the output of last layers:  `fused_1 = concatenate([averagepool, maxpool])`
3. Create conv or other dense layers : `top_model = Dense(4096, activation='relu',name="dense_one")(fused_1)`
4. Create final model: `model = Model(inputs=[model1.input, model2.input], outputs=[top_model])`
5. Fit the model: `history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, ...)`

Comment: in any case the zip shows error maybe you can use function def myGenerator (gen1, gen2):
  while True:
    xy1 = gen1.next()
    xy2 = gen2.next()
    yield ([xy1[0], xy2[0]], xy1[1]) and pass generator variables to the functions train_generator = myGenerator(train_generator_yuv, train_generator_ycrcb)

Comment: I'll verify this answer after a while. Been missing out sometimes to continue with the idea.

Comment: The `.next` method for a big dataset would break the program.

Comment: what is the size of your data

Comment: 10.24 GB of about 42K JPEG files, to give you the perspective.