# Add sequential features to 1D CNN classification model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, text-classification

I am building a 1D CNN model using Keras for text classification where the input is a sequence of words generated by `tokenizer.texts_to_sequences`. Is there a way to also feed in a sequence of numerical features (e.g. a score) for each word in the sequence? For example, for sentence 1 the input would be ['the', 'dog', 'barked'] and each word in this particular sequence has the scores [0.9, 0.75, 0.6]. The scores are not word specific, but sentence specific scores of the words (if that makes a difference for how to format the input). Would an LSTM be more appropriate in this case?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use 2 channels in the input tensor.

In better terms, if you input before had shape: `(batch_size, seq_len)`

Now you could have: `(batch_size, seq_len, 2)`

If you look at the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/), you see that with the parameter `data_format` you pass a string, one of `channels_last` (default) or `channels_first`. In this case the default would be fine, because the `2` (number of channels is last).

You can just stack the 2 input arrays into a tensor with this shape.

Now if you use a word embedding probably the number of channels will not be 2, but it would be `embedding_dim + 1`, so the final input shape would be: `(batch_size, seq_len, embedding_dim + 1)`

In general you can also refer to this other [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233377/keras-sequential-model-with-multiple-inputs).

In any case, both CNN 1D and LSTM could be good models... but this you need to discover yourself depending on your task, data and model constraints.

Now as a final remark, you could even think of a model with multiple inputs one the word sequence and the other the scores. See this [documentation page](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#manipulate-complex-graph-topologies) or this random [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/) I found on the internet. You can again refer also to the same [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233377/keras-sequential-model-with-multiple-inputs).