# Loading images with multiple numeric values for neural network

Tags: python, image-processing, neural-network

I have a dataset of images and their two regression values in the CSV file. For example, "img1.jpg" has two numeric values "x_cord" and "y_cord" stored in annotation.csv. I want to train my neural network with images and these two values from CSV file. But I'm not able to load them. Please someone give a solution to load both of them together and give them as input to the neural network.
Many thanks.

I'm not able to load them together. I have tried flow_from_dataframe, but it only takes one numeric value so I don't know how to load multiple numeric values with an image.

Comment: I think you might be looking for multiple input networks, [here is an example of that.](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#models-with-multiple-inputs-and-outputs) And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233377/keras-sequential-model-with-multiple-inputs) is another one to check.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I want to give images plus numeric values as input.